# Why can I not answer my own question - is this a bug?

Tags: bug, self-answer

Back in July of last year I [asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1465061/how-to-trace-the-reason-for-firefox-tab-crashes-in-virtualbox). I have an answer I would like to give, but I am not allowed to.

At the base of the page, it says:

> **Highly active question**. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

I have 73 reputation points, and I am signed in, so I meet the criteria for answering, but there is no answer box rendered for me. Moreover, I thought that this restriction would not apply, given that it is my own question, and self-answers are welcomed across the Stack Exchange sites.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is a quirk rather than an outright bug. I suspect several features came in to play.

1. Your question had been protected due to poor answers such as people effectively saying "me too".
2. You had a cross-site association bonus applied to your account
3. Due to bounties posted you were below 101 reputation
4. Protected questions require 10 reputation *on the site you are asking on* meaning you need 111 reputation to answer, when association bonus is taken into account
5. As a result you lack the reputation to answer protected questions.

I have unprotected the question, see if you can answer it now.

Comment: I can answer now - thanks! I wonder if it was intended that these restrictions would apply to self-answers - while I support question protection in general, it seems odd to assume that a low-rep OP would also give a LQ (self) answer.

Comment: (I guess that this behaviour applies right across the network - maybe there is an over-Meta question that would reveal if this was intentional).

Comment: @halfer I found [Improve “Protected Question” message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati) which corroborates that association bonus is effectively void as far as protected questions go and why. I cannot see why it is simply subtracted though and that part could be considered a bug, you do have a good few upvoted questions so you have earned rep here. It might be worth asking about this edge case  on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright, thanks - will do. I have added an answer, so it can be protected again if you wish.